# Get tree list of records for a specific user

Tags: sql, sql-server, treeview

I have these two tables:

**Table1 (Messages)**

MessageID | UserID | Subject | TextM | FatherMessage | ....

**Table2 (Tb_Registration)**

UserID | Username | ....

Using the following query in a TreeList, where I set DataKeyNames=MessageID and ParentDataKeyNames= FatherMessage, I get a tree of the messages and the relevant answers to them for all users. [image: picture]:

```
SELECT Messages.Subject,
       Messages.FatherMessage,
       Messages.TextM,
       Messages.MessageID,
       Tb_Registration.Username
FROM   Messages
       INNER JOIN Tb_Registration
               ON Messages.UserID = Tb_Registration.UserID
ORDER  BY Messages.MessageID ASC
```

My challenge now is to get exactly the same but for a specific user and I cannot figure out how to make such query. I mean, the FatherMessage from a specific user and all the submessages associated to it. All messages on level 0 (new messages) have the filed FatherMessage=null in the table. All other messages (answers) have as FatherMessage, the MessageID of the parent Message.

Here is some sample data:

```
MessageID | UserID | Subject | TextM | FatherMessage |
    1       user1       X       some       null
    2       user2     null      text         1
    3       user3     null      text         1
    4       user4     null      text         2
    5       user4      y        text       null
```

Expected output from the above (where Username = user1) is:

```
MessageID | UserID | Subject | TextM | FatherMessage |
    1       user1       X       some       null
     2      user2     null      text         1
      4     user4     null      text         2
     3      user3     null      text         1
```

Some help will be appreciated.

Comment: you have to use `Recursive CTE`. If possible edit your question with `Sample data` and `expected output`

Comment: @NoDisplayName thanks for the hint. I have update my question adding sample data and expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this..

```
DECLARE @Messages TABLE(MessageID int,
                        UserID VARCHAR(100), 
                        Subject varchar(150), 
                        TextM varchar(250), 
                        FatherMessage int)
INSERt INtO @Messages
(MessageID ,UserID , Subject , TextM , FatherMessage )
VALUES
(1,'user1','X ','some  ',null),
(2,'user2','null','text',1),
(3,'user3','null','text',1),
(4,'user4','null ','text ',2),
(5,'user4',' y  ',' text',null)


    ;with cte(MessageID , UserID , Subject , TextM , FatherMessage) AS (
    select * from @Messages where UserID='user1'
    UNION all
    SELECT m.* FROM @Messages m INNEr JOIN cte ON m.FatherMessage=cte.MessageID
    )
    SELECT * FROM cte
```

**OUTPUT**

```
    MessageID   UserID  Subject TextM   FatherMessage
--------------------------------------------------------
       1         user1     X    some    NULL
       2         user2    null  text    1
       3         user3    null  text    1
       4         user4    null  text    2
```